# Using ng-lightning for components shows 404 tether error

Tags: angular

Using angular 2. Added the ng-lighning to my seed project.
I added the CDN to the index.html and then included the component in boot file. The page shows error related to tether... any idea or suggestion on what im doing wrong

**INDEX.html:**

```
  <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/ng-lightning@0.8.0/ng-lightning.bundle.js"></script>
```

**BOOT.ts**

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from "@angular/router";
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from "@angular/common";
import { provide } from "@angular/core";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { MessageService } from "./messages/message.service";
import {provideNglConfig} from 'ng-lightning/ng-lightning';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [MessageService,
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}),
  provideNglConfig()

]);
```

**Error**

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3000/tether"
tether
Error: patchProperty/desc.set/wrapFn@http://localhost:3000/js/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:769:27
    Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/js/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:24
    Zone</Zone</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:3000/js/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:29
    ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:3000/js/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:29

    Error loading http://localhost:3000/tether as "tether" from http://localhost:3000/ng-lightning/popovers/trigger
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SystemJS, you should also configure the path to cdn for tether in your `systemjs.config.js`. Something like this:

`paths: {
  'tether': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.2.0/js/tether.js',
}`

I hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am was also getting the same issue.

---

### Fix

Edit the systemjs.config.js file and add the following. You are likely to have other entries in these structures, so just add these as new lines.

```
var map = {
    'tether':                     'node_modules/tether/dist/js',
  };

var packages = {
    'tether': { main: 'tether.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };

var ngPackageNames = [
    'tether',
  ];
```

---

### Original Issue

As soon as I load provideNglConfig() into my bootstrap command, I see the errors below.

My bootstrap file is quite simple:

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app.routes';
import {provideNglConfig} from 'ng-lightning/ng-lightning';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ HTTP_PROVIDERS, APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provideNglConfig() ]);
```

This also occurs on a component if I add NGL_DIRECTIVES to the directives.

```
import { NGL_DIRECTIVES } from 'ng-lightning/ng-lightning';
directives: [ AppHeaderComponent, NGL_DIRECTIVES ]
```

In both cases, if I leave the import statements there, but take out the mentioned components, all works fine again.

```
login:41 Error: (SystemJS) Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading 
http://localhost:3000/tether(…)(anonymous function) @ login:41ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:3000/tether 404 (Not Found)scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM35636:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1059(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1767ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1766(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2795(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3365(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3677(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4069(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4532(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4801(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:413ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426

zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:3000/tether 404 (Not Found)scheduleTask @ zone.js:101ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:336Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:273(anonymous function) @ zone.js:122send @ VM35636:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1059(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1767ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:584(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1766(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2795(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3365(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3677(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4069(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4532(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4801(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:413ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
```